# How does the Magento backend sales quote work?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

In general, I'm looking for a tutorial or walkthrough of how the payment system works in magento.  Specifically, I'm interested in the process of creating an order from the admin backend.  I have a customer credit extension that isn't working properly when creating an order from the admin backend.  I've tried tracing through the code and there's SO much going I can't make heads or tails of it.  There's the quote, then the addresses, which have totals associated with them, etc, etc...it's all very confusing.  I know this is a bit of an open ended question, but if anyone has any good resources on exactly what does what and how it all works that would REALLY help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this tutorial can give you some basic idea:
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-quote-order-invoice-workflow/

Comment: That does provide some basic information but there are definitely still many unanswered questions.  Plus, once you get an idea of how it works on the frontend you have to re-learn everything for the backend since they are only slightly similar.  Between the javascript calls that update different sections to understanding how the Address objects relate to the quote/order/invoice, it's a mess!  I did find this tutorial (http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method) which helped a bit, but any other info would be appreciated!